# How to get two separate dispform for two views of the same list ? (No Infopath since SharePoint Standard)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a list with two different views , but when i click on view item the form of both remains same . Is it possible to have two dispforms for the two views.

Thanks,

Comment: If the list items should have different fields, you can create two content types. Each content type has own form.

Comment: @Alexander you should put that as an answer, that is the most feasible solution :) For different views, you can make two views each for each content type.

Comment: How can we set one content type for one view

Answer (score 0):

If the list items should have different fields, you can create two content types. Each content type has own form.

> How can we set one content type for one view

You can go to view settings and set expression in the filter section.

Comment: Thank you for responding, In filter section we have columns, how to set expression like I mean content type